# Install latest MariaDB properly via apt

Tags: bash, mariadb

Currently I'm running this helper function in my synced shell environments on all my Linux/macOS devices;

```
install_mariadb() {
    local mariadb_version_test
    local mariadb_version
    local repo_arch
    local distro

    mariadb_version_test="$(which mariadb)"
    readonly mariadb_version_test

    if [[ -f "${mariadb_version_test}" && "${1}" != "--reinstall" ]]; then
        return
    fi

    if $IS_LINUX; then
        mariadb_version="$(get_latest_mariadb_version)"
        readonly mariadb_version

        if $IS_PI; then
            distro="debian"
            repo_arch="arm64"
        else
            distro="$(grep -Eo "^ID=(.*?)$" "/etc/os-release" | tr -d 'ID=')"
            repo_arch="amd64"
        fi
        readonly distro
        readonly repo_arch

        sudo apt update -y
        sudo apt install -y build-essential software-properties-common gnupg2 ufw
        sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys "https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc"

        # TODO :: Cleanup old entries from the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* file(s)?
        sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=${repo_arch}] http://mariadb.mirror.globo.tech/repo/${mariadb_version}/${distro} ${VERSION_CODENAME} main"

        sudo apt update -y
        sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client
    elif $IS_MACOS; then
        brew install mariadb
    fi

    mariadb --version
}
```

I would prefer to install it on the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ properly as well, but even with `arm64` (can't find any correct `armv7l` builds in their repo listing), but then it fails because it refuses to use `debian` and forces `Raspbian` and then gives this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException(
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/bullseye
```

As an easy readable aid, this is what the final `add-apt-repository` output is when all variables are combined;

```
deb [arch=arm64] http://mariadb.mirror.globo.tech/repo/10.10.2/debian bullseye main
```